# UPDATE Field Based on Array Selection From Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of checkboxes that are in a while loop.  The code is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.*,b.* FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN b_report_expenses b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE a.TASK_ID=$taskid");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $invoiceID = $row['ID'];
        $invoiced = $row['INVOICED'];
        $mondayBill = number_format($row['MON_BILL'],2);
        }
        if ($invoiced == 0){    
        print "<input type='checkbox' name='rep[]' value='$invoiceID'>Reference Number: $invoiceID<br />";
        }
        elseif ($invoiced == 1){
        print "<em>Reference Number: $invoiceID has already been invoiced</em><br />";  
        }
```

This is just a snippet of the code but what I want to do is, on the processing page I would like to update a field in the database (INVOICED field) from 0 to 1 based on which checkboxes are ticked.  I have tried:

```
foreach ($_POST['rep'] as $index => $id) {
$sql4="UPDATE b_report_week SET INVOICED = 1 ";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql4))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 }
```

This however updates all the checkboxes that are on display as it would do, I understand I need a WHERE clause in there but not sure how I can do it per checkbox that is selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause is missing in the UPDATE statement which is why all the records are being updated. Try this:

```
UPDATE b_report_week SET INVOICED = 1 WHERE `ID` = $id
```

However, a better approach would be to execute only one UPDATE statement instead of calling UPDATE statement in a loop like this:

```
UPDATE b_report_week SET INVOICED = 1 WHERE `ID` IN (2,5,8)
```

Here 2, 5, 8 are the IDs of selected checkboxes